# SharePoint 2013 left navigation - How to add links?

Tags: 2013, navigation, paging

I recently seen on a portal site where the left navigation was grouped by 5 different categories.

Sales
 link 1
 link 2

Support
 link 1
 link 2
 link 3
 link 4
 link 5
 1 - 5 >

If you notice there are other links under support and pagination is setup for that. How can I do the same? add pagination for left navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way out of the box to achieve this. I would handle this with custom JavaScript.

Use the SharePoint [navigation settings](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Configure-navigation-items-on-the-Site-Navigation-Settings-page-6ad7a02c-8724-4a51-9972-dc4537566cb2) to setup the links as you want them using headings to group items. Then [load your custom JS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75863/add-javascript-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-2013) to manipulate which navigation children are currently visible and which are hidden.

I have not done this exact thing you are asking about but have implemented something similar where all children are hidden using JS. They are then made visible when a parent link is clicked.

I would be happy to post a snippet if it would help but not sure how much detail you want.

Comment: Would fly out menus solve this? If so it is pretty easy to do no JS needed (just need to change a value in the masterpage). You could also hide them based on audience I think.

Comment: In my understanding, I didn't think fly outs would solve this question? I just mentioned my example to explain how one might customize the navigation using JS.